# Is it possible to get function from bunch of points?

Tags: interpolation, mathematical-modeling, data-analysis

I have some points which I know the position in 3D. and that points made in sequence. 
for example,

. (x1,y1,z1)

```
                                 (x5,y5,z5)
                                     .         
                                              .(x6,y6,z6)
     . (x2,y2,z2)           .(x4,y4,z4)

                 .
              (x3,y3,z3)
```

and from this bunch of points, is it possible to get function like y(x) = bla bla~
 if it possible, how to I get it?

### I tried to do that using interpolation, but I can't.

Alright, I have these bunch of points
[image]
and If I plot it in 3d, it looks like these.
[image]
I also only make interpolation between two each markers.

And, I want to make a function to calculate parametric curves. 
but I have no Idea.

Comment: you can't expect that the function $y$ only depends on $x$ unless all the points lie in the same plane. But of course, interpolation can be made in 3D.

Comment: Do you have a model or are these random points ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Actually, I have a model, but the points are too a lot, I just show random points.

Comment: So, if you have a model, is it a problem of finding the parameters ? Tell me about the model, please.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Then, Can it make any function in 3d, not using interpolation?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes, it is. I wanna make some kinds of spline stuff.

Comment: Is this what you look for : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I editted with model. could you give some Idea of it? and can bicubic_interpolation be used in 3d ?

Comment: Bicubic splines are for 3D problems.